# iOS: How to regenerate UIImageView with UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uibutton

I have a very simple app that has an UIImageView and an UIButton. Every time the user presses the button the image will move -44 in x direction and -41 in y direction. My question is: how can I set an "if statement" so that when the UIImageView reaches a certain point in the screen (maybe the end of the screen) it will regenerate at other point in the screen (maybe the beginning of the screen)?

Something like: if imageOne reaches x point and y point, then regenerate imageOne at x point and y point.

This my code:

file. h

```
{

IBOutlet UIImageView *ImageOne;

}

-(IBAction)Button:(id)sender;
```

file. m

```
-(IBAction)Button:(id)sender{


//ImageOne moving down the screen

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f
             animations:^{

                 ImageOne.center = CGPointMake(ImageOne.center.x -44, ImageOne.center.y +41);

             }];
```

What do i need to implement in my code?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to use "animateWithDuration" for your purpose.

Let's say you have imageOne and you are moving it left in the x direction and when the image
moves out of the screen, you want it to move back to the middle of the screen.
Try this

```
-(IBAction)Button:(id)sender{
   //reset image onto screen.
   if(imageOne.center.x < 0){
    imageOne.center = CGPointMake(200, imageOne.center.y);

    }

    //move image left
    imageOne.center = CGPointMake(imageOne.center.x-44, imageOne.center.y);
}
```